# How to format CPF in a column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
       import pandas as pd
       df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2],
                           'Name': ['ALEX', 'ALAN', 'PAUL'],
                           'CPF_Num': ['01598432545',
                                       '47896321478',
                                       '47522101001']})
```

I need to format the CPF information column, called 'CPF_Num', to the following format: XXX.XXX.XXX-XX. So I developed the following code, based on what I googled:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237371/como-formatar-o-cpf-corretamente-em-python#:~:text=%C3%A9%20s%C3%B3%20pegar%20os%20grupos%20de%20n%C3%BAmeros%20e%20concatenar%20com%20a%20pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o.&text=Para%20nada%20precisa%20criar%20classe,mas%20elas%20s%C3%A3o%20sempre%20opcionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237371/como-formatar-o-cpf-corretamente-em-python#:%7E:text=%C3%A9%20s%C3%B3%20pegar%20os%20grupos%20de%20n%C3%BAmeros%20e%20concatenar%20com%20a%20pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o.&text=Para%20nada%20precisa%20criar%20classe,mas%20elas%20s%C3%A3o%20sempre%20opcionais)

```
       df1['CPF_Num'] = df1['CPF_Num'][:3] + "." + df1['CPF_Num'][3:6] + "." + 
                        df1['CPF_Num'][6:9] + "-" + df1['CPF_Num'][9:]
```

However, this code does not result in the desired output. The output is being:

```
      id    Name    CPF_Num
       0    ALEX    NaN
       1    ALAN    NaN
       2    PAUL    NaN
```

The desired output is:

```
      id    Name    CPF_Num
       0    ALEX    015.984.325-45
       1    ALAN    478.963.214-78
       2    PAUL    475.221.010-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str` accessor

```
df1['CPF_Num'] = df1['CPF_Num'].str[:3] + "." + df1['CPF_Num'].str[3:6] + "." \
                 + df1['CPF_Num'].str[6:9] + "-" + df1['CPF_Num'].str[9:]
print(df1)

# Output
   id  Name         CPF_Num
0   0  ALEX  015.984.325-45
1   1  ALAN  478.963.214-78
2   2  PAUL  475.221.010-01
```

**Variant**

```
s = df1['CPF_Num'].str
df1['CPF_Num'] = s[:3] + '.' + s[3:6] + '.' + s[6:9] + '-' + s[9:]
print(df1)

# Output
   id  Name         CPF_Num
0   0  ALEX  015.984.325-45
1   1  ALAN  478.963.214-78
2   2  PAUL  475.221.010-01
```

**Alternative** with `str.replace`:

```
pattern = r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})'
df1['CPF_Num'] = df1['CPF_Num'].str.replace(pattern, r'\1.\2.\3-\4', regex=True)
print(df1)

# Output
   id  Name         CPF_Num
0   0  ALEX  015.984.325-45
1   1  ALAN  478.963.214-78
2   2  PAUL  475.221.010-01
```